# How to use cookie with cURL in PHP

Tags: php, cookies, curl

I read some questions and answers on stackoverflow but I still can't understand how it works.
I have a cookie.txt, what should I use to setup this cookie with cURL.
I tried

```
 curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,"/cookies.txt");
```

but it does not work.
The fact is I can't get data from my URL without a cookie which define a place. I did it with Google Chrome and I tried to catch the right cookie to put it in the same directory that my php file.

When I try

```
echo var_dump($wrap);
```

it displays string '' (length=0) .

Do you know why is wrong ? What have I missed ?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do? Send or receive cookie? You can use CURLOPT_COOKIE if you just want to pass cookie value.

Comment: `in the same directory that my php file` then you're using the wrong path with `/cookies.txt`

Comment: @nacholibre I try to use (send) a cookie I already have on my computer.

Comment: @Shikiryu Oh the path is wrong so

Answer (score 0):

First off, enable CURLOPT_VERBOSE which will help you to diagnose exactly what is happening. Cookie issues can be somewhat precarious and without knowing exactly what is being sent/received it can be difficult to diagnose.

Second, ensure the specified path /cookie.txt actually exists. If in the same dir, ommit the forward slash.

Third, read the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

> CURLOPT_COOKIE      The contents of the "Cookie: " header to be used in
>   the HTTP request. Note that multiple cookies are separated with a
>   semicolon followed by a space (e.g., "fruit=apple; colour=red")
>
> CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE      The name of the file containing the cookie data.
>   The cookie file can be in Netscape format, or just plain HTTP-style
>   headers dumped into a file. If the name is an empty string, no cookies
>   are loaded, but cookie handling is still enabled.
>
> CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR   The name of a file to save all internal cookies to
>   when the handle is closed, e.g. after a call to curl_close.

Comment: Thank you @Rijndael I will try to use CURLOPT_VERBOSE with CURLOPT_STDERR very soon (I don't know how it works yet). I set the path to cookies.txt without /. I hope I will find out. I will be back to tell it later.